# Getting date and file from Firebase realtime database and storage

Tags: javascript, firebase, es6-promise

I need to retrieve data from realtime database and file from firebase storage. Structure of firebase realtime databse is

```
Object {
    "2020": Object {
         "duG0Y3r3FvBk2foJj0RC": Object {
              "details": "chapter 2",
              "title": "differential calculus",
        
      },
    },
},
```

firebase storage also has the same file structure. chapters/yr/duG0Y3r3FvBk2foJj0RC/filenamepdf

my code in the Componenetdidmount is shown below

```
    firebase.database().ref("chapters").once("value", (userSnapshot) => {
      const temp = [];
      const fls = [];
      userSnapshot.forEach(yr => {
        const year = yr.key;
            yr.forEach(element => {
                const key = element.key;
                const title = element.child('title').val();
                const details = element.child('details').val();
                var pref = 'chapters/'+year+'/'+key+'/';                
                var listRef = firebase.storage().ref(pref);
                  listRef.listAll().then((res) => {
                    const filelist = [];
                        res.items.forEach((itemRef) => {
                          var files = itemRef.name;
                          listRef.child(files).getDownloadURL().then((fileurl)=>{
                            filelist.push({fileurl});
                            }).catch(function(error) {
                            // Handle any errors
                          });
                        });
                      }
                    }).catch((error) => {
                      console.log(error)
                    }); 
               temp.push({key, year, details, title, filelist});
            }); 
        });
     });
    this.setState({temp});
});
```

above code is getting data and url but the issue is with the promise or async/await. code get finished and sets state before fetching the url. How can I write statement so that the fetching url is finished before completing the set state.

Answer (score 0):

You can use .then() function of Promise,
Here is simple example:-

```
const fetchSubjects=(key)=>{

      db.collection("Utilities").doc("Subjects").get()
      .then(result=>{
        let data = result.data();
         /*process Data*/
        setSubjects(subjects);
      });

    }
```

I am using hooks so the method 'setSubjects()', you can do setState there